# Create upload files api in next.js

Tags: next.js

It is possible to create a file upload api in next.js? (using /api directory)
Or I must use an external third party service online?
Can't find any example online.
Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can upload files with Next.js API routes.

### Example with default Next.js body parse

*API handler*

```js
export default (req, res) => {
  // req.body contains a content of an uploaded file + headers
}
```

`req.body` is a `string` that contains related HTTP headers in the beginning like

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydj2uhBXPZtD3nte3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="your_input_name"; filename="your_file_name.json"
Content-Type: application/json
your file content is here!
```

So, you would need to take out the content from it. Probably there are some packages that can do it.

Alternatively, you can parse the request with a third-party package.

### Example with [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

*API handler*

```js
import { IncomingForm } from 'formidable'
// you might want to use regular 'fs' and not a promise one
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'

// first we need to disable the default body parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  }
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  // parse form with a Promise wrapper
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm()
    
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve({ fields, files })
    })
  })

  // read file from the temporary path
  const contents = await fs.readFile(data?.files?.nameOfTheInput.path, {
    encoding: 'utf8',
  })

  // contents is a string with the content of uploaded file, so you can read it or store
}
```

Code in the examples above for the illustration purpose only. At least need to wrap it in `try catch` statement with proper error handling.