# How to upload a file with NextJS and formidable?

Tags: next.js, formidable

I am trying to utilize formidable to access a file and eventually post it to a file storage system by following this post: [Create upload files api in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465564/create-upload-files-api-in-next-js). I am logging the data, but am getting confused about the output. When I try and access data.files.resume.filepath I get undefined.

The data looks like:

`{ fields: {}, files: { resume: [ [PersistentFile] ] } }`

And when I log data.files.resume I get this which shows the filepath:

```c
[
  PersistentFile {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function (anonymous)] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    lastModifiedDate: 2023-02-09T01:59:50.924Z,
    filepath: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\21eef37a9191459ae49bb110f',
    newFilename: '21eef37a9191459ae49bb110f',
    originalFilename: 'thankyou.pdf',
    mimetype: 'application/pdf',
    hashAlgorithm: false,
    size: 57285,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      fd: null,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\21eef37a9191459ae49bb110f',
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 57285,
      closed: false,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    hash: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
]
```

and when I log the data.files.resume.filepath I get `undefined`

**Front End Form Submit:**

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("resume", resume);

const response = await fetch("/api/apply", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
});
```

**NextJS API:**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return;
  }

  // parse form with a Promise wrapper
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });

  console.log("------");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("------");
  console.log(data.files.resume);
  console.log("------");
  console.log(data.files.resume.filepath); // this logs undefined

  res.status(200).json(data);
}
```

I followed this StackOverflow article: [Create upload files api in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465564/create-upload-files-api-in-next-js) and have tried logging each step, but still get undefined for the filepath. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`data.files.resume` is an array

use `data.files.resume[0].filepath` instead or use first values helper

```
import { firstValues } from 'formidable/src/helpers/firstValues.js';
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `data.files.resume[0]`. Because resume is an object inside that resume, you have persistence at index '0'. At persistence, you have the file name, path, original name, etc. Using the data, you can get your file.

I was just looking for that, so I decided to implement it in Express JS to know what exactly happens here, so in my NextJS project I have invested my knowledge.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).